# Признаки профессиональной деградации программиста?

Tags: работа

Как вы думаете, какие основные, наиболее заметные (а лучше наоборот - малозаметные)  и опасные признаки деградации программиста, как специалиста (если таковые можно выделить вообще) - кроме субъективных ощущений индивидуума, разумеется (или только на них и нужно ориентироваться)?

Что Вы делаете, чтобы поддерживать себя в тонусе?

Выполняете ли вы некие дополнительные "телодвижения" для поддержания формы?

Comment: @SoloMio, именно деградировать довольно сложно - если один раз узнал, как работает $X и долго это без проблем вспоминал, то это будет довольно сложно забыть. Другое дело *не успевать за фронтом волны* и *подзабывать недавно освоенные вещи*, и то, и другое обычно связано с угасанием интереса к проф.деятельности. Это довольно общеболезненная тема, но каких-то тестов по ней нет (я бы посоветовал просто зайти на тематический ресурс и посчитать количество неизвестных слов). Предложения по борьбе с ней тоже довольно стандартные: неглубокие отдых, пляж, экстрим, смена деятельности и/или коллектива,

Comment: хобби, либо более глубокие - терапевт, выяснение удовлетворенности жизнью, выяснение, хочется ли самому заниматься программированием. Бывает еще так, что проблемы произрастают из другого места - начиная от банальной болезни, кончая тем, что написанные проекты не взлетают (потому что клиенты не знают, зачем их заказывают, например).
Лично для меня самый действенный мотиватор - нахождение в кругу людей, чей уровень значительно превышает мой.

В общем, если я говорю все по теме - это довольно стандартная вещь, обычно называется перегреванием, нужна встряска, если не поможет - копать глубже.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Мне кажется, признак деградации — потеря интереса к работе. Если программисту не хочется развиваться, узнать что-то новое, выучить новый трюк, новый язык, начать писать правильнее, значит, он начал деградировать.

Если программист не совершенствуется, не растёт над собой, если ему его же собственный код двухлетней давности не кажется отвратительно корявым — он начинает умирать как программист.

Если не двигаться вперёд, получится только назад.

Как сказала одна [умная женщина](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_%28%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%29) (правда, не программистка),

> ...здесь, знаешь ли, приходится бежать со всех ног, чтобы только остаться на том же месте! Если же хочешь попасть в другое место, тогда нужно бежать по меньшей мере вдвое быстрее!

---

*Дополнение.* То, что человек потерял интерес к программированию, не является негативной характеристикой самого человека. Может быть, он стал старше, и ему интересно теперь не писать программы, а управлять коллективом. Или нянчить внуков. Или конструировать роботов, завоёвывать цивилизации, спасать белых китов, озвучивать мультфильмы, знакомиться с людьми на улице или научиться разбираться в сигарах и сортах коньяка. Но при этом он станет более хорошим начальником (дедушкой, конструктором, ...), и менее хорошим программистом. Никакой трагедии в этом нет.

Comment: @VladD, не всегда работа (основной источник дохода) и хобби (именно программирование (причем, возможно, какие-то его конкретные аспекты)), полностью совпадают.

А вот найти источник дохода, совпадающий с хобби -- это просто мечта.

--

А по делу, когда начинаешь меньше *придумывать*  и писать новых программ.

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, программист, который не любит свою работу, не сможет быть _хорошим_ программистом и не поднимается выше уровня ремесленника. Если работа неинтересная (не тот язык, не те задачи), надо (1) искать себе более сложную задачу, (2) если не получится, искать где самореализоваться (другая работа, open source, хэшкод, что угодно).

Answer (score 4):

Я бы наверное сформулировал немного иначе: если программист всегда кодирует только за деньги - то это первый (и самый верный) признак профессиональной деградации программиста (и не только, кстати, программиста).

Программист должен всегда развиваться, а развиваться это означает самому копаться, выискивать, учиться - то есть то за что обычно деньги не платят. Если человек работает только за деньги, то это уже мертвец. Конечно, сие никоим образом не отменяет что программист должен работать бесплатно. Программист получает деньги, за применение знаний, которые он хорошо знает и одновременно должен учиться.

Answer (score 3):

Формальный признак деградации — прекращение роста.

Как только прекратились поиски ответов на новые вопросы, освоение новых практик, языка, применений — наверное, тогда.

Для поддержания в тонусе *специально* что-то делать не приходится, само выходит: для стартапа постоянно что-то новое пробую; хожу на [meetup](http://www.meetup.com/)'ы; отвечаю на вопросы тут; задаю вопросы и ищу ответы на SO. Всегда полон буфер "хорошо бы, да нет пока времени" — покрыть все тестами, применить ту или еще вон ту технологию. Как только время появляется, берусь.

Специальную «зарядку» для поддержания в тонусе делаю только в контексте физических упражнений : )

P.s. здорово помогает, как в любом обучении, общаться с теми, кто круче. Будь то пинг-понг, иностранный язык, или программирование. Поэтому если на работе стал самым крутым по важным для себя аспектам, пора уходить : )

Comment: Только надо четко осознавать, что наличие или отсутствие роста -- это всегда субъективно.

Answer (score 2):

Когда понимаешь, что пора найти другую работу, но остаешься на прежнем месте из-за хорошей з/п. Про случаи, когда остаешься даже при плохой з/п, даже упоминать не стоит.

Comment: Хм... Ну, вот я вполне дошёл до того состояния, что какой бы не была интересной другая работа, и как бы не хотелось... Если зарплата меньше, или загрузка больше при том же уровне, или даже на дорогу  больше времени тратить - в пень. Потому что семью содержать, родителям-пенсионерам помогать, дом строить, c собаками служебкой/спортом заниматься, а в сутках всего 24 часа, руки всего две и т.д. Но что-то всё никак не сдеградировать :-)

Comment: Не стоит оправдываться. Но вопрос был о том, что ведет к деградации. Когда-то мой выбор всегда зависел от ключевых вопросов "интересно ли это и будет ли это меня максимально развивать". Сейчас эти вопросы обиженно стоят в сторонке, т.к. появились другие приоритеты.

Comment: Это не оправдание, а одно из самых простых доступных объяснений того, что "зарплатные" признаки, и пути - полная чушь. Причём оба.

Comment: Вы выбрали слишком узкие критерии оценки. Работа за з/п на дядю - не единственный способ реализовать себя как программиста. В сфере фриланса простая работа со стабильной небольшой зарплатой - это полезное подспорье к большим гонорарам за нерегулярные проекты.